Error when installing realtime kernel
Good day all.
I have an Ubuntu 24.04.1 OS on my MSI Vector GP68 HX 13V laptop (Intel i9, RTX 4080). It's running okay, however I've tried to enable the realtime kernel provided with the free Ubuntu Pro subscription and I'm getting errors while installing.
I started the installation with "sudo pro enable realtime-kernel" as written in the documentation, but I got an unclear system error while installing (something regarding the kernel and also add-apt or something like that). This is the log (pretty long): https://easyupload.io/p108mv
So I wanted to try with sudo apt install --fix-broken:
~$ sudo apt install --fix-broken 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto   
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
5 non completamente installati o rimossi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 0 B di spazio su disco.
Configurazione di linux-image-6.8.1-1011-realtime (6.8.1-1011.11)...
Configurazione di linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime (6.8.1-1011.11)...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.1-1011-realtime
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'ma
ke' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.8.1-1011-realtime IGNORE_XEN
_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.1-1011-realtime/build L
D=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime is not sup
ported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.1-1011-realtime (x86_64
)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.1-1011-realtime/x86_64 failed for nvidia(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.1-1011-realtime
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime (--co
nfigure):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime script 
post-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 11
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux-headers-
realtime:
 linux-headers-realtime dipende da linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime; tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-headers-realtime (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di linux-realtime
:
 linux-realtime dipende da linux-headers-realtime (= 6.8.1-1011.11); tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-headers-realtime non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-realtime (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di ubuntu-realtim
e:
 ubuntu-realtime dipende da linux-realtime; tuttavia:
  Il pacchetto linux-realtime non è ancora configurato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché il messagg
io di errore indica la presenza di un fallimento precedente.
                                                            Segnalazione apport 
non scritta poiché il messaggio di errore indica la presenza di un fallimento pr
ecedente.
         Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché è stato raggiunto il valore mass
imo di MaxReports
                 pacchetto ubuntu-realtime (--configure):
 problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Elaborazione dei trigger per linux-image-6.8.1-1011-realtime (6.8.1-1011.11)...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.1-1011-realtime
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; [ ! -h /usr/bin/cc ] && export CC=/usr/bin/gcc; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'ma
ke' -j16 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.8.1-1011-realtime IGNORE_XEN
_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/6.8.1-1011-realtime/build L
D=/usr/bin/ld.bfd CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT= modules...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime is not sup
ported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.1-1011-realtime (x86_64
)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/560.35.03/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.1-1011-realtime/x86_64 failed for nvidia(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.1-1011-realtime
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto linux-image-6.8.1-1011-realtime (--conf
igure):
 il sottoprocesso installato pacchetto linux-image-6.8.1-1011-realtime script po
st-installation ha restituito lo stato di errore 11
Segnalazione apport non scritta poiché è stato raggiunto il valore massimo di Ma
xReports
        Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 linux-headers-6.8.1-1011-realtime
 linux-headers-realtime
 linux-realtime
 ubuntu-realtime
 linux-image-6.8.1-1011-realtime
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Any idea of what to do from here? :')
